# the origin parameter in fseek function in c

Tags: c

piece of code from my homework

```
int main()
{
    Sums("input.txt");
    return 0;
}
void Sums(char* filename)
{
    FILE* f, * h;
    int i, len, sum;
    char num[3];
    if ((f = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
        GetLost("Input Error");
    if ((h = fopen("temp.txt", "w")) == NULL)
        GetLost("Output Error");
    fseek(f, 0, 2);
    len = ftell(f) / 2;
}
```

the input.txt is 1101112607080

My question is shouldn't the 3rd parameter in fseek function be one of SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END?
and the value of len is 6 in this code, what is the meaning of 2 in the fseek origin parameter?

Comment: Why there is no prototype declared for the function `Sum`?

Comment: understood nothing ...

Comment: @haccks void Sums(char* filename);

Comment: @haccks i didnt copy the whole code

Comment: @snr my question is what's the meaning of the number 2 in fseek(f, 0, 2);

Comment: This is homework?  Automatic 10 points off for `int main()`.  This is not C++

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I been doing this my whole life lol

Comment: @MustafaShama you can accept my answer by clicking tick on the left on my answer under voting.

Answer (score 1):

In `stdio.h`,

```
#ifndef SEEK_SET
#define SEEK_SET    0   /* set file offset to offset */
#endif
#ifndef SEEK_CUR
#define SEEK_CUR    1   /* set file offset to current plus offset */
#endif
#ifndef SEEK_END
#define SEEK_END    2   /* set file offset to EOF plus offset */
#endif
```